# Python - Can not solve LP

Tags: python, scipy, linear-programming

I have been trying for some time to solve the following linear problem in Python:

```
minimize{x1,x2}, such that:
x1+2*x2 = 2
2*x1+3*x2 =2
x1+x2=1
x1>=0
x2>=0
```

I have tried the pulp and linprog libraries (`from scipy.optimize import linprog`) but I have not got anywhere. The first point is that both these libraries expect me to input some sort of "objective function" to minimize, while I am looking to minimize my variables as such (meaning essentially to verify that I do not have infintely many solutions). However, I tried to minimize the following objective function:

`x1 + x2`

judging that this is pretty much equal to minimizing x1 and x2 since they are both greater than 0. The second point is that both pulp and linprog seem unable to handle "Infeasible" cases. This means that when both these libraries come in front to an infeasible problem, instead of printing out something relevant (i.e.: "problem can not be solved"), they instead start dropping constraints till they get an answer. For example, the above problem is infeasible, since there are no such numbers x1 and x2 that satisfy all the above equations. Now linprog in this case prints out the following

```
message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
```

and

```
x: array([ 0.,  0.])
```

from which I understand that the solution is x1=0 and x2=0, which is of course incorrect.

My next move is to code everything myself with nested for loops and conditional statements to depict the constraints, but I don't wanna go there yet. Moreover, I am in search of a solution that can be easily generalized, to say 100+ different equations (since I will be doing stuff in n-dimensional spaces of Real Numbers) and 60+ variables (x1, x2 , ... , x60).

Comment: Can you include the code for the objective function you have tried to write this far?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is trivial and i don't get why you did not show any code if you are having problems:

Code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import linprog

A_eq = np.array([[1, 2],  # x1+2*x2
                 [2, 3],  # 2*x1+3*x2
                 [1, 1]]) # x1+x2
b_eq = np.array([2,2,1])
c = np.array([1,1])       # min x1 + x2

res = linprog(c, A_eq=A_eq, b_eq=b_eq, method='simplex')
print(res)                                         # fails as expected;
                                                   #   crypted message (for non-experts)

# scipy >= 1.0 !!!
res = linprog(c, A_eq=A_eq, b_eq=b_eq, method='interior-point')
print(res)                                         # warns about problem-status in presolve

res = linprog(c, A_eq=A_eq, b_eq=b_eq, method='interior-point', options={'presolve': False})
print(res)                                         # declares infeasible
                                                   #   turning-off presolve sometimes needed
                                                   #   for more accurate status messages
                                                   #   (which is documented!)
```

Additional info needed:

> bounds : sequence, optional
>
> (min, max) pairs for each element in x, defining the bounds on that parameter. 
>   Use None for one of min or max when there is no bound in that direction. **By default bounds are (0, None) (non-negative)** If a sequence containing a single tuple is provided, then min and max will be applied to all variables in the problem.

**None of these runs will output status=success! (and flags corresponding to some exit-state are set)**

Go check what attributes are set. (I'm not showing those as my scipy-install is a bit customized with some private debug-prints)

#### Now some word of advice:

- don't trust `scipy.linprog(method='simplex')`

  - if you don't trust me: look up github-issues or search on SO
  - (i would have deprecated that function a long time ago; if no one is fixing it)
- try `scipy.linprog(method='interior-point')`

  - if you can live with a non-simplex approach
  - if you have scipy >= 1.0
- Coin's [pulp](https://github.com/coin-or/pulp) brings, compared to scipy, a very very advanced LP-solver ([Clp](https://projects.coin-or.org/Clp), favouring Simplex) and using it correctly, it won't output wrong status' messages here for your problems!

  - Clp is in my opinion the most advanced open-source LP-solver
- If you don't have an objective: set the objective vector `c` to zeros!

#### And just to be clear

> This means that when both these libraries come in front to an infeasible problem, instead of printing out something relevant (i.e.: "problem can not be solved"), they instead start dropping constraints till they get an answer. For example, the above problem is infeasible, since there are no such numbers x1 and x2 that satisfy all the above equations.

**No!**. No LP-solver, should ever return a successful-solution when the problem is infeasible (that's something else than saying a problem is infeasible!).

Additionally, most LP-solvers support infeasibility-detection (all simplex-type solvers; not all IPM-like solvers, but scipy's) and will return a feasibility-certificate when the problem is infeasible!

Only broken solvers `linprog(method='simplex')` might be troublesome here.

(The above is valid for problems which are not implying numerical-trouble, which is always possible using finite-memory floating-point math; except for maybe specialized rational-type solvers. This applies even to the most advanced commercial solvers and it's not important for your problem here)

**Edit: Approach using Coin's** [pulp](https://github.com/coin-or/pulp):

```
from pulp import *

prob = LpProblem("problem", LpMinimize)
x1 = LpVariable('x1', lowBound=0., upBound=None, cat='Continuous')
x2 = LpVariable('x2', lowBound=0., upBound=None, cat='Continuous')

# The objective function is added to 'prob' first
prob += 1.*x1 +1.*x2, "min x1 + x2"

# Constraints
prob += 1.*x1 + 2.*x2 == 2, "1*x1 + 2*x2 == 2"
prob += 2.*x1 + 3.*x2 == 2, "2*x1 + 3*x2 == 2"
prob += 1.*x1 + 1.*x2 == 1, "1*x1 + 1*x2 == 1"

# Solve
prob.solve()
print("Status:", LpStatus[prob.status])
for v in prob.variables():
    print(v.name, "=", v.varValue)
print("Objective: ", value(prob.objective))
```

Output:

```
Status: Infeasible
x1 = 0.0
x2 = 1.0
Objective:  1.0
```

Comment: Is it possible to present the pulp code for the above problem?

Comment: @user37143 I have added a simple example.

Comment: Thank you. My issue is that I have 300 constraints. Using linprog I can simply depict these constraints as an array (A_eq). Can I do something similar with pulp?

Comment: Not much you can do, besides trying to use ```lpDot()``` and co. That's why i don't use pulp much. I like the math-based formulation. (pulp's huge advantage is ease of use for simple problems and the solver coming with it). So in this case: just do the loop (grab row, use lpDot for constraint). 300 constraints is nothing! Any reason not to use scipy? My favourite though is cvxpy, although more targeted at nonlinear, but convex problems. But there is support for Cbc/Clp too, with a more tough install, and GLPK, with a medium-hard install.

Comment: I keep getting an error  `message: 'Iteration limit reached.'`. I tried raising the "maxiter" parameter up to even 5.000.000 but still.... So I was wandering whether there is a better alternative.

Comment: In scipy? Well... it's possible you did something wrong (or let's say: you passed it a very very unstable problem; max_iter >= 100 is never really needed; if it's not working with 100; don't go towards thousands; it's an IPM after all).

Comment: I doubt it's that I did something wrong, since there are cases in which it works and others in which I get this message. But maybe you are right and I throw some unstable stuff in there.

Comment: Without reproducible code it's hard to analyze. Read the potential warnings outputted by scipy's presolve. And if ok with you, increase the tolerance (though already quite high), decrease alpha0, turn-off cholesky, turn-off mehrotra, ...  a lot of approaches